# Gson "toJson" on annonymus objects returns null

Tags: java, android

I wanted to make an anonymous object to String using Gson.

my object is not null, but yet the method "toJson" return null.

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: is your object of generic type?

Comment: you can see in the printscreen. only Strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [users guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-):

> Gson can also deserialize static nested classes. However, Gson can not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args constructor also need a reference to the containing Object which is not available at the time of deserialization.

Gson doesn't do the serialisation and returns null.  You can use a static nested class instead of a anonymous inner class.